# Best Environment for job portal site

Tags: asp.net

I planned to develop the job portal as similar to naukri/monster.

I'm going to do through ASP.NET. For this, what is the best environment. 
At early, I planned to use "Dot Net Nuke" and then I came to know that its for CMS, 
Shall I go with MVC framework for this or anything is there which is good than MVC. I don't have any experience on web based application, but I'm good enough in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CMS isn't going to be flexible enough to allow you to accomplish the types of things you'll need to do for a job board type website. I would stick with MVC or even WebForms if you're completely new to the web.

Unless this is a pet project to help you learn how to program for the web, you may want to start smaller and get some experience before trying something like this. Developing for the web is a completely different animal than just knowing some c#. There are a ton of other technologies you will need to know, including HTML, JavaScript or JavaScript library such as jQuery, stateless design, etc.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar question while we were developing a job site for our client. After weighing all the pros and cons we finally decided to go with PHP. We found that the performance of the site in terms of speed was much better and needed far less resources. In the end the client was happy with the decision we helped them make.